# Validate with useEffect in react Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a code like that and I want when errors === 0 , then setAmount, however, appears the following error:

index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

```
    const [values, setValues] = useState({a:2, b:3})
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({a:2, b:3})
    const [Amount, setAmount] = useState({a})

    useEffect(()=>{      
        setErrors(validate(values));

        if(Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
          setAmount(a+b)
        } 

    }, [errors, values.a, values.b])
    return{values, errors}
```

How can I solve this issue?  I want when I change the values a and b if there aren't errors execute the setAmount.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime the effect will run, it gonna `setErrors(validate(values));`, and because `errors` are trigger the effect to run again, it an endless loop. add checker before `setErrors(validate(values));`

---

```
 useEffect(()=>{ 
    errors != validate(values) && setErrors(validate(values));

    if(Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
      setAmount(a+b)
    } 

}, [errors, values.a, values.b])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'll check it.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked for me but I appear this message:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'errors',  'validate', and 'values'.

Comment: You might add those as well to the dependecy array if you want this error to go away, anyhow it just warn and not error

Comment: Can you add your current error?maybe its another issue?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting in infinite loop is that every time you render, the effect runs and calls `setError` with a new object. Since you just set state, you render again, and repeat the loop

I don't think you need three states here. It looks like you want errors and `amount` to always be a reflection of what's in `values`. In that case, just use one state, and calculate the others based on that state.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({ a: 2, b: 3 });
const errors = validate(values);
const amount = Object.keys(errors).length === 0 ? values.a + values.b : 0; // Not sure what value you want in the case where there are errors, so i assumed 0

return { values, errors };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check it.  I have errors and setErrors because it's a custom hook and I need to return the errors.

Comment: Other than the lines of code in your example, do you ever need to call `setErrors`?

Comment: I wasn't asking about `errors`, i was asking about `setErrors`. If you never need to set the state, that's a good sign that it shouldn't actually be a state.